# Knockout custom binding for jQuery UI Sortable - strange behavior

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js

I'm using jQuery Sortable and Knockout to maintain an array.

http://jsfiddle.net/daniel_white/KrGY8/3/

Notice when you drag the items, they duplicate or disappear.

Anyone know how I could fix this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

KO's mapping of items gets a little messed up based on empty text nodes when you are moving things around using jQuery UI sortable.

You can either eliminate the text nodes in your "template" like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/KrGY8/5/

Or remove the existing item and put it back to the right spot in two steps (updating the observableArray twice):  http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/KrGY8/4/

I also wrote a binding plugin to work with jQuery sortable in Knockout that provides some additional features here: https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable

Comment: I used your plugin and my initial impression is that it works great! Thanks for providing it.

Comment: Thanks RP, this saved quite some time for me.. I went with 2nd suggestion as well and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Awesome plugin; I struggled for hours before I found this, and it works like a charm. Wish I could upvote more than once.

Comment: I'm using an extended version of the sortable plugin to allow multiple selected items to be moved together, so I cannot use your plugin currently, and thus I used the first tip about empty text nodes and fixed my template accordingly. Now everything seems to be working fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to work around this problem is to first clear your binded observableArray, like this:

```
list([]);
```

Then updated it with the correct array:

```
list(actualArray);
```

Check the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KrGY8/231/)